# Finding permutations without repetition

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

My question reads as follows

Find the number of passwords that use each of the digits $3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9$ exactly once

In how many of the passwords

(a) are the first three digits even?

(b) are the three even digits consecutive?

(c) are the four odd digits consecutive?

(d) are no two odd digits consecutive?

Now for the first part I got $7!$ And then moved on to a. I did $3!4!$ and got $144$ but I am not too sure this is correct.

For b through d I'm confused as to what is meant by consecutive.

When I attempted b I got something like $7!-5(4!)$ because I took the total subtracted my five cases where we can have $468$ and the multiplied by $4!$ Since the odds still need to be arranged. I am not sure if my technique is correct so this is confusing me for c and d.

Comment: For the first, count possible permutations between $3,4,5,6,7,8$ and$9$.

Comment: Consecutive means that they appear right after one another. One example for $b$ would be $4683579$ and another would be $3568497$. However, $3465987$ wouldn't work because $8$ is not adjacent to $4$ or $6$.

Comment: @KevinLong so I can have say 486 not just 468 in that order?

Comment: @Correct, you can have any permutation of $468$ in your password, as long as there are no odd numbers in between the evens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answers for the number of passwords and part a are correct. Now you need to allow your three consecutive even numbers to take any place in the password, not just the first three places, as long as they remain consecutive. So you still have $3!*4!$, but now you take into account the number of places the even numbers can take. What you have right now ($7!-5*4!)$ counts the number of passwords that don't have $468$ occurring in any place. Part c is similar to part b, but with the odd numbers. For part d, note that you have more odd numbers than even numbers (exactly one more, to be precise). How can you arrange them to get a password where no two odd numbers are adjacent?

Comment: I worked out b and got 5(3!)(4!)=720. C is similar but not its four digits since there are four odd so I have 4(4!)(3!)=576. For d I worked out a chart and got 15 possible combinations thus 15(4!)(3!). I'm not too sure if theses are fine.

Comment: You're right for b- you have $3!$ way to order the evens, $4!$ ways to order the odds, and $5$ ways to arrange the odds around the evens ($0$ to the left and $5$ to the right, $1$ to the left and $4$ to the right, up to $5$ to the left and $0$ to the right). You're also right for c, since you can have $0,1,2$ or $3$ of your evens to the left of your odds, and the rest to the right. I'm not sure where you got that $15$ in part $d$, however. If my first number is odd, the next must be even, then odd, etc, so we get $oeoeoeo$, where $o$ is odd, $e$ is even. Can my password start with an odd in d?

Comment: I did odd even odd then odd even even odd, then odd even even even odd, and so on and then switched to odd in the second place and so on. This is how I got 15.

Comment: Oh. Wait. I just considered two odds not the other two that would also have to be non consecutive.